# Issuing a command in the shell a program is run from

Tags: c, unix

I have a program which hacks around in the user's shell configuration file (by placing a . (execute) command for an auto-generated alias file) and I'm having trouble figuring out how to run commands in the parent shell, i.e. without forking into a new shell.

I only need to run a command to execute the alias file so that the "program" can be used without logging in and out. Surely there must be another way to interact with the shell beside forking.

N.B.: When I say "forking" I mean both using `system()` and `execl()` - as I said, I want to send the command to the shell hosting the program, not a new instance of it.

Comment: I don't think it's possible at all (at least I don't know any ways), but why don't you just run a new shell from your program with all the aliases already generated?  It may look like here: `sh` executes `your_program && exit`, `your_program` does what it needs and executes another `sh` to provide a user with a command line. When it exits, the first `sh` also exits.

Comment: In general, a child process can't make its parent process do anything.  You are seeking to subvert the way the shell works.  There might be ways to achieve it, but they will be contorted and probably non-portable at best, and more likely nearer 'impossible' than 'realistic'.  You probably need to rethink what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some thinking about your use case, I suppose what you want to do, that is, to signal your parent shell to reload the configuration, is impossible, but what you can do here is to reverse the control.

What I mean is, don't think how to make your parent shell do something, but let it do it for you. If you have a program that fixes shell configuration, make a shell wrapper for it:

```
/path/to/program
. ~/.bashrc # or any other way to reload the shell config
```

and call your program using `. wrapper.sh` to make sure it will be executed in the context of the current shell. In this way the program will make changes to the configuration but will not bother with interacting with its parent, and the calling shell will just reload itself after the program finishes.